# Checkbox javascript 2 condition to delete

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I have checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkboxid" name="checkboxname">
```

and button delete

```
<button id="btnDeleteid" name="btnDeletename">Delete</button>
```

How does the javascript look like to delete with 2 condition?

1. The checkbox is **not** checked and button is pressed -> show the alert like "Checked First" and back to before page
2. The checbox is checked and button is pressed -> make confirmation yes or no if yes or no still back to before page

I've already tried this

```
<button id="btnDeleteid" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete? This action cant be undone')" name="btnDeletename">Delete</button>
```

but only 1 condition, need help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Below is what you want

[Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/W6bGS/) `</>`

Answer (score 0):

When rendering this stuff, check whether checkbox is checked using
    `$('#checkboxid').prop('checked')`. If so enable delete button
    `$('#btnDeleteid').removeClass('disabled')`. Otherwise disable
    it`$('#delete').addClass('disabled')`

Listen on checkbox change to disable/enable delete button (the above).

```
    $('#checkboxid').on('change'), function() {
      if ($('#checkboxid').prop('checked')) {
         $('#delete').removeClass('disabled');
       } else {
         $('#delete').addClass('disabled');
      }
    });
```

Now listen on delete click.

```
    $('#delete').on('click'), function() {
      if ($('#delete').hasClass('disabled')) {
        return; // Do nothing when button is disabled.
      }

      confirm('Are you sure you want to delete? This action cant be undone');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a function binding to your del button `onclick` event. And better not write js code in HTML codes.

The code is like this:

```
function del(){
    var sureToDel = false;
    if(!checkInput.checked){
        alert("Must check first!");
    }else{
        sureToDel = confirm('Are you sure you want to delete? This action cant be undone');
        if(sureToDel){ do something .....}
    }
}
```

Here is [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/bsnEB/) of your logic

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkboxid" name="checkboxname">
  <button id="btnDeleteid" onclick="deleteCheckBox()" name="btnDeletename">Delete</button>
```

JS

```
function deleteCheckBox(){
   if (document.getElementById('checkboxid').checked){
       var answer = confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this checkbox?');
      if (answer)
       {
      $("#checkboxid").remove();
       }
     }else{
         alert("Pls check the checkbox.")
     }
   }
```